# setting chart.js stacked bar chart data dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, chart.js2

my stacked bar chart looks like below

```
  <canvas baseChart
                        [datasets]="barChartData"
                        [labels]="barChartLabels"
                        [options]="barChartOptions"
                        [legend]="barChartLegend"
                        [chartType]="barChartType"
                        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
              </div>
```

I have seen examples where a particular data array is replaced. This works for me as well. However, in my case i want to replace entire dataset. The way it looks in my code is:

```
  this.barChartData = [{"data":[3,0,0,0],"label":"dialog"},{"data":[16199,0,0,0],"label":"AtkBBBFuseFeedsFrontPage"},{"data":[52799,0,0,0],"label":"SandboxHover"},{"data":[11343,0,0,0],"label":"ManageSandboxes"}]
        this.chart.chart.data.datasets = this.barChartData
         this.chart.chart.data.labels = ["session1","session2","session3", "session4"]
          this.chart.chart.update()
```

However, this does not work. And chart does not render the above data at all.

Also, if I put the same data at the initialization like below then it works fine. so it's not the problem with data.

```
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective)
  public chart: BaseChartDirective;
public barChartOptions:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
    }
  };
     public barChartLabels:string[] = ["session1", "session2", "session3", "session4"];
      public barChartType:string = 'bar';
      public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

      public barChartData:any[] = [{"data":[3,0,0,0],"label":"dialog"},{"data":[16199,0,0,0],"label":"AtkBBBFuseFeedsFrontPage"},{"data":[52799,0,0,0],"label":"SandboxHover"},{"data":[11343,0,0,0],"label":"ManageSandboxes"}]
```

Old data:

```
public barChartData:any[] = [{data:[0,0,0,0],label:"dialog"},
                              {data:[0,0,0,0],label:"AtkBBBFuseFeedsFrontPage"},
                              {data:[0,0,0,0],label:"SandboxHover"},
                              {data:[0,0,0,0],label:"ManageSandboxes"}]
```

new data

```
 this.barChartData =  [{"data":[3,0,0,0],"label":"dialog"},{"data":[16199,0,0,0],"label":"AtkBBBFuseFeedsFrontPage"},{"data":[52799,0,0,0],"label":"SandboxHover"},{"data":[11343,0,0,0],"label":"ManageSandboxes"}]
```

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: added more relevant part. there is nothing else.

Comment: is it throwing any error in console..?? 
Actually you don't need to do chart.chart.datasets = this.barChartData.

suppose you need to refresh that on button click. In the event of that button click if you assign this.barChartData = [your new whole data objects here]

but here in the example I have seen that your data is same, so may be that is the reason you are not seeing any change in the UI

Comment: simple assignment does not work. i tried that already

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working but you don't see the change because your previous data and the changed data is exactly same. so, it is not updating. I ran your code and it is working.

html: i have created an extra button to change the data.

```
<canvas baseChart
                        [datasets]="barChartData"
                        [labels]="barChartLabels"
                        [options]="barChartOptions"
                        [legend]="barChartLegend"
                        [chartType]="barChartType"
                        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
    </canvas>

     <button (click)="changeData()">CLICK</button>
```

ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'myapp';

  public barChartOptions: any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
    }
  };
  public barChartLabels: string[] = ["session1", "session2", "session3", "session4"];
  public barChartType: string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend: boolean = true;

  public barChartData: any[] = [
    {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
      {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
      {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C'}];

  public changeData(): any{
    this.barChartData = [
      {data: [10, 2, 80, 81, 36, 55, 40], label: 'Series D'},
      {data: [28, 87, 40, 19, 67, 27, 9], label: 'Series E'},
      {data: [18, 48, 66, 9, 58, 27, 40], label: 'Series F'}
    ];
  }
}
```

my code is perfectly working.

Comment: what if u change the shape of the data. so initialize it as public barChartDate:any[]=[{data:[65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'}] and the on click button do what u did. does that work for u?

Comment: you can change the shape. you are assigning a new data when you do this.barChartData = [something]. so it will refresh everything and draw that with new data. Can you give the data.. the previous one and the changed one. I am not sure what is not working. everything is working fine here.

Comment: another thing you used @viewchild here. I don't think it is needed.

Comment: added the data i am using

Comment: here is my observation. you change the data completely but dimensions cannot be changed. so if u initialize the barChartData with say for rows then you cannot dynamically change it to have 5 rows.  if u do that then only first 4 row data will be updated.